# regex - match a word and replace content before it

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, match

I have several files with this line:

`<2-10 digits> ; word`

I want to replace all of the digits that come before that word with something else. How can I do that?

Comment: Pls tell us which language/tool you're using for regex.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to use something simple like sed in a bash for loop.

Comment: Can you pls provide some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Sure. I have multiple files, and each file has that specific line. I want to edit all of the files at the same time to have the updated digit field.

Comment: I have provided one sed example below. If you want to save changed filed you can use `sed -i` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 sed -i -e 's/.*word/something;word/g' <filename>
```

To loop over multiple files in a directory. I am assuming .txt file as the file extension:

```
for i in `\ls -1 *.txt`
  do
    sed -i -e 's/.*word/something;word/g' $i
done
```

Note: `sed -i` will modify the file interactively. So, test the command without `-i` option to check this is what you want and then go for it...

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** sed example:

```
s="999 abc 1234 ; word 567"
echo $s | sed 's/^\(.* \)[0-9][0-9]*\( ; word.*\)$/\1something\2/g'
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
999 abc something ; word 567
```